# ifort and icc installation on ubuntu14.04

Tags: compiler

I want to install Intel fortran compiler(ifort) and icc on my laptop with ubuntu14.04 OS. I have read from several sources that it is free for Linux distributions but when I want to get it from official the Intel website, it only shows a trial version. note that I want to use these compilers to compile RegCM4 (regional climate model) and WRF (weather research forecast model).

it is possible either `gfortran` and `gcc`, but it worked before, and its been one month that the model crash while compiling with `gfortran`.

Any Idea?

Comment: ICC has never been *free* for Linux. It was at one time, free for academic use on Linux. Perhaps no longer.

Comment: any idea about using another compiler on ubuntu14.04 which is free?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to believe that your recent compiling failures would be overcome by switching to an alternate compiler?

Comment: according to user guide of codes I mentioned above, it says that I can use gfortran, ifort or pgi fortran

Answer (score -1):

ifortran is not for free. I think gfortran is going to do the job. I never faced such problems with gfortran. 
Just make sure that gcc and gfortran are up-to-date:

```
gcc --version
gfortran --version
```

Comment: The point is not only about functioning (as asked by the used) but also about run time. Most code used in the field of earth system modeling has long run times. ifort compiled code runs considerably faster than gfortran compiled code. Therefore, it is reasonable to use ifort (if available).